# Calcular costo de llamadas

Tags: c++

Vengo hacer una consulta por un ejercicio.

https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Llamadas-telefonicas/#problems

Tengo que ingresar la clave y los minutos y luego calcular el costo de la llamada, pero no logro calcular el costo si los minutos están unidos a la clave.

Dejo lo que tengo echo

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int CLAVE;
int NUMIN;

cin>>CLAVE>>NUMIN;

switch(CLAVE)
{
    case 12: NUMIN*=2;break;
    case 15: NUMIN*=2.2;break;
    case 18: NUMIN*=4.5;break;
    case 19: NUMIN*=3.5;break;
    case 23: NUMIN*=6;break;
    case 25: NUMIN*=6;break;
    case 29: NUMIN*=5;break;
}

cout<<NUMIN;

  
}
```

Gracias

---

Fui probando y algo que no aclaré en el código. Es que por `input` solo tiene que entrar, por ejemplo: `23,5` y el resultado tendría que ser `30`. No me pide primero la clave y luego los minutos.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int CLAVE = 0;
    float CLAVE2 = 0;
    int NUMIN = 0;

    cin >> CLAVE2;

    CLAVE = CLAVE2;

    NUMIN = CLAVE2 * 10;
    NUMIN = NUMIN % 10;

    switch(CLAVE) {
        case 12: NUMIN *= 2;break;
        case 15: NUMIN *= 2.2;break;
        case 18: NUMIN *= 4.5;break;
        case 19: NUMIN *= 3.5;break;
        case 23: NUMIN *= 6;break;
        case 25: NUMIN *= 6;break;
        case 29: NUMIN *= 5;break;
    }

    cout << NUMIN;
}
```

Probé con esto y funciona si me piden que ingrese, por ejemplo, `23.5`. Si pongo `23,5` la "," no la reconoce.

---

Modifique una variable del código original a float y funciono.

Supongo que fue un error mío suponer que debía ingresar todo junto como mostraba el ejemplo a seguir.

Gracias por la ayuda y por la aclaración sobre la configuración local, no sabia como solucionar eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de solucionar este problema es modificar la lista de separadores de `cin`:

```
struct comma_as_separator : std::ctype<char> {
  comma_as_separator()
    : std::ctype<char>(get_table())
  {}
  
  static mask const* get_table()
  {
    static mask rc[table_size];
    rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
    return &rc[0];
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), new comma_as_separator));
    
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    
    std::cout << a <<'-' << b;
}
```

La estructura `comma_as_separator` se limita a configurar la coma para que `cin` la trate como un separador. La línea que se encarga de esto concretamente es:

```
rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
```

Con este diseño puedes cambiar a tu antojo el comportamiento de la entrada estándar de C++.

Si esto es demasiado complicado para ti puedes forzar una lectura caracter a caracter para detectar la coma a mano:

```
int a = 0;
char c;
std::cin >> c;
while (c != ',')
{
    a *= 10;
    a += c - '0'; // Convertimos el char en un dígito numérico
    std::cin >> c;
}

int b;

std::cin >> b; // El resto de la secuencia se puede leer directamente
```

En cualquiera de los dos casos, en `a` obtendrás lo que haya antes de la coma y en `b` lo que se encuentre después

> Probé con esto y funciona si me piden que ingrese, por ejemplo, 23.5. Si pongo 23,5 la "," no la reconoce.

El problema es la configuración local:

- La configuración local en España implica el uso de la coma como separador de decimales y el punto como separador de miles.
- La configuración local americana implica el uso **del punto** como separador de decimales y **la coma** como separador de miles.

Debido a estas diferencias, o lees caracter a caracter, o configuras el *locale* para que no se use la configuración local por defecto sino la que a ti te interesa.

Si la solución por defecto hubiese sido tan simple como leer el dato y separar la parte entera de la decimal no te habría escrito una respuesta tan larga